# RESTfulness of SOA with Single Entry Point

Tags: rest, soa, entry-point

I have a service-oriented architecture with a single gateway for all client requests.  I like this because the gateway is tidy, hides all "internal" services, and acts as a dispatcher and homemade load balancer.

Because of my design, however, the client only ever knows about "one" resource.  And must send up messages that have requested operations and their parameters defined in JSON.

```
{
    "operation" : "Login",
    "parameters" :
    {
         "username" : "John",
         "password" : "1234"
    }
}
```

Should I be sad because my architecture is not RESTful?  Am I not leveraging HTTP like REST prescribes?  Please critique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if "sad" is the right word, but one of the arguments in favor of REST, especially as implemented in using HTTP "properly" is that it provides to you, for free, the following (taken from Fielding's dissertation):

- Client-Server interaction, separating UI from data storage
- Stateless Server, improving reliability and scalability
- Client Cache, reducing some network traffic
- Uniform Interface, decoupling implementations from the services they provide
- Layered System, where each component is only concerned with those just below or just above it
- Representation Orientation, where you think in terms of resources
- HATEOAS, where your application essentially navigates links
- A constrained interface, with a small number of verbs (e.g. GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, and only about 3 others)

When you go with SOAP or another RPC solution, instead of REST, you are in theory giving up some but not all of these characteristics.  You may be giving up client cacheability and you are thinking procedurally, and you probably can't use all the safety and idempotency conditions that RESTafarians exploit to a tee.

RESTful services have become very popular and not by accident.  But does that mean you *have* to build RESTful services or that non-RESTful services are inherently much worse?  I don't think so.  I've done a couple RESTful SOAs for two different companies and while I prefer to SOAP (which seems bulky these days) and to home-grown APIs like yours (which, even if elegant, aren't standard), I don't diss other approaches and dismiss them as inferior.

If you are going to go with your own API, and return only 200s and 404s, and do everything with GET, then yes your API is conceptually simple and perhaps it will work fine for you.  But if you need a variety of media types, and you have persistent storage requirements containing collections that are often appended to, deleted from, created and updated, then learning modern RESTful API design will at least open up new ways of thinking for you.

Bottom line is don't feel sad nor feel like you have to go to REST because everyone else is doing it.  But the advantages are real and REST is not just hype.

Comment: Thanks.  As a hypothetical starting point to making my service described above more RESTful, what would you change?  Would you send up the same JSON to the same login service, and get back a list of URLs from which to further proceed (i.e., links that represent the operations available to a client once it has been successfully authenticated)?  Along with which verb (i.e., GET, POST, PUT or DELETE) to use with which URL?  Question's open to all.

Comment: Can you give examples of some of your other "services"?  Login is something that more traditional RESTful services just kind of leave to the browser to do in response to receiving a 401.

Comment: Regarding login, for security I had in mind a model that works off a token being granted to the client upon successful authentication.  This token would be used in any further communication and operations.  But your comment has made me a bit uncertain.  What would the typical client or browser do in response to getting the RESTful 401?

Comment: RESTful systems have `POST host.com/orders` to create the order (with JSON or XML in the entity describing the new order.  The server would create and assign the id and return HTTP 201.  Also `GET host.com/orders` to see all orders with query params to search a restricted set, and `GET host.com/orders/5` to view just order 5.

Comment: Re authentication, you can set up your browser to put up its own login box in response to a 401.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Basically you have a home brewed SOAP style RPC using JSON instead of XML.

You might ask whether it's worth reinventing that with JSON rather than using a SOAP stack, but if you're talking to JavaScript, it might simply be easier to to use than SOAP, plus there's no burden of conforming with the SOAP standards/tool sets.

Other than that, seems fine to me.

Comment: Without making all my services available as separate and distinct URLs, there's no way to consider myself RESTful, is there?  Surely there are more security concerns with exposing 10 distributed services than with exposing one and having the other nine sit behind a firewall, am I right?

Comment: REST has a lot of constraints, but the multiple URLs is one of them as the resources are modeled via URLs.